# row_prefix in happybase table.scan not working with str variable

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

I am using the row_prefix in the table.scan method to filter the rows. The problem is that the function works when a string literal is used. However, if a variable is used no data is returned.

For example, the following code is working

```
connection = happybase.Connection(connect string)
table = connection.table('table')
table = table.scan(row_prefix='abc001', include_timestamp=False)
```

But the following code does not return any data

```
connection = happybase.Connection(connect string)
table = connection.table('table')

query = '\'{0}{1}\''.format(args['str1'], args['str2'])
table = table.scan(row_prefix=query, include_timestamp=False)
```

There is no error in the 2nd case.

Comment: try printing the value of "query" before passing to scan. are you getting the same value as first query?

Comment: yes, the query string is correct. In fact, I took the generated string and copied it in the scan method and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `'\'{0}{1}\''` with `'{0}{1}'` in query value and try again

Comment: It worked after the suggested formatting change. Thanks!